# Any existing way via Reflection to watch a property setter?

Tags: debugging, xamarin.ios, portable-class-library, code-injection, system.reflection

Is spying the setter of a property something that can be achieved via Reflection?

Let's say, for instance, that I have a method somewhere that receives the following:

```
private void LogPropertySetter(string propertyName, string newPropertyValue)
{
    Logger.Log("Property " + propertyName + " has been set to " + newPropertyValue);
}
```

And I have this property somewhere in the application that I want to observe:

```
public int FlyingCatsAmount { get; set; }
```

Note that I did deliberately not place a private/public set of variables here so that the solution applies to properties.

Could I add a call in the setter like that via Reflection or with any other API (in debug) that allows to modify the setter from code and not in AOP (PostSharp)?

```
LogPropertySetter([getPropertyNameViaReflection], value);
```

Comment: You may want to look into Aspect Oriented Programming tools like Postsharp. Reflection only enables you to inspect, not to generate or alter (byte)code at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

No, nothing like this can ever be done with reflection. Reflection is not a debugger. The debugger API can.

Comment: This is interesting. If you say the debugger API can, you mean it can achieve a similar result? Like calling a method or an event handler when a setter is called for a specific property? Is this existing in PCL?

Comment: @LéonPelletier - Note that such simple methods likely will be inlined in JITed code. You likely will need to setup hardware breakpoints on data changes (that's what VS doing when you want to track changes at particular location in memory). There are definitely more achievable ways if you writing your own code.

Comment: The debugger can actually replace the bytecode of the method ;)

Comment: Your last comment interests me TomTom, as what I want to do will only run in a debugging context.

Comment: Then you are out of luck - a .NET runtime can only have one debugger attached so your code can not attach then.

Comment: And this let appart, can this debugger API be used on a mono / PCL project? ie. Monotouch / Monodroid?

Comment: Who cares? First - in some months .NET is public from Microsoft on Linux. Second, this question does not state Mono. So, if you want a mono specific answer, then it is YOUR job to put the tag into the question, not mine to read your mind.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't state Debugging API neither. I'll ask a new question and delete this one. I flagged it as "too broad" since I'm not interested in my question anymore, having no way to achieve my goal using Reflection.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .net 4.5 you can call a method and get the callerpropertyname

For instance:

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{}
```

From .net 3.5 to 4 you can use this method:

```
   protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expProperty)
    {
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(((MemberExpression)expProperty.Body).Member.Name);
    }
```

and call it in the setter like:

```
    public string DisplayNameExtensionMobileNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _DisplayNameExtensionMobileNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            _DisplayNameExtensionMobileNumber = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.DisplayNameExtensionMobileNumber);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question which is specific about using reflection.

Comment: @KeithPayne i dont think so: he wrote: "Could I add a call in the setter like that?

LogPropertySetter([getPropertyNameViaReflection], value);" and that is possible with my solution. greez

Comment: There's a reason why the OP wants to do it with reflection. It is implied in his desire for aspect-oriented logging. The reason is that the OP does not want to pollute his setters with logging code. Additionally, as mentioned by @LéonPelletier, adding code to accessors is a performance hit beyond the added lines of code because the accessor is no longer in-lined.

Comment: @KeithPayne but fact is - his question contains: "Could I add a call in the setter like that?"

Answer (score 0):

Pre-.NET 4.5, it is possible to get the current property name using the following:

```
private int _x;
public int X
{
    get { return _x; }
    set
    {
        _x = value;
        string propName = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name.Substring(4);
        LogPropertySetter(propName, value);
    }
}
```

The CurrentMethod name in this case will be `set_X`, so take off the first 4 characters to get back to `X`.

There is a big caveat to this however in that the method will probably be optimized away by the compiler and so not work as you want it to. You can set the following attribute to stop it being inlined, but this can cause a performance penalty and is generally not recommended:

```
public int X
{
    get { return _x; }
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    set
    {
        _x = value;
        LogPropertySetter(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name.Substring(4), value);
    }
}
```

If you are using .NET 4.5, I would recommend going with Cadburry's suggestion.